# Linux Terminal Stop Command in repeat

Tags: linux, terminal, command

I right now try to stop my current command and restart it every hour right now I only restart it by

```
while true; do homebridge; sleep 3600; done
```

This let me run the command homebridge every hour once, but before the do homebridge I want to stop the "homebridge" command so it restart it every hour.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the command in the background, so the script can keep running without waiting for it to exit. Use `$!` to get the PID of the background process.

```
while true; do
    homebridge &
    pid=$!
    sleep 3600
    kill $pid
done
```